# Count the number of all the shortest paths for any two vertices in a graph

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

For any pair of different vertices  in a given undirected graph G= , I want to find the number of all the shortest paths ("SP", in abbreviation) (it is not required or necessary to find/print the exact vertices on a certain path). For example, for the following graph given in edge-list format, there are two SPs: (1,3,2) and (1,4,2).

**vertex** =

```
1   3
2   4
1   4
2   3
1   8
4   7
3   6
5   2
```

I want to implement this algorithm based on Floyd-Warshall algorithm , which is a famous algorithm based on the idea of dynamic programming to find the value of the shortest path for each pair of vertices in O(N^3), say the result is an 2D array a[n][n]. n is the number of vertices. For the above graph, it is:

```
0   2   1   1   3   2   2   1
2   0   1   1   1   2   2   3
1   1   0   2   2   1   3   2
1   1   2   0   2   3   1   2
3   1   2   2   0   3   3   4
2   2   1   3   3   0   4   3
2   2   3   1   3   4   0   3
1   3   2   2   4   3   3   0
```

The code for constructing graph matrix **G** and solving for matrix **a** is as follows:

```matlab
v = vertex(:,1);
t = vertex(:,2);
G = zeros( max(max(v),max(t)));

% Build the matrix for graph:
for i = 1:length(v)
    G(v(i), t(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)) + 1; 
    G(t(i), v(i)) = G(v(i), t(i)); % comment here is input is bi-directional
end

a = G;
n = length(a);
a(a==0) = Inf;
a(1:n+1:n^2)=0; % diagonal element  to be zero

for k = 1:n
    for i= 1:n
        for j= 1:n %  for j=i+1:n
            if a(i,j) > a(i,k) + a(k,j)
                a(i,j) = a(i,k) + a(k,j);
%                 a(j,i) = a(i,j);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now, let's defined a 2D array b[n][n] as the number of ALL the SPs for each pair of vertices. For example, we expect b[1][2] = 2. 
I wrote the following code in MATLAB (if you are not familiar whit MATLAB, just treat it as a pseudo-code). It gives almost correct values for all the pairs **except several wrong values for certain pairs**. For example. after running the cod,e b[5][8] = 0, which is wrong (**correct answer should be 2**)

```matlab
%% 
% find the number of ALL SP paths for ALL pairs based on the "a" array:
% b is a two-dim array, b(i,j) is the total number of SP for pair( i,j)
b = G;
for k=1:n
    for i=1:n
        for j= i+1:n

            if(i==j)
                continue; % b(i,i)=0
            end

            if (k==j) % the same as : G(k,j)==0
                continue;
            end

            if(k==i && G(k,j)~=0)
                b(i,j) = 1;
                continue;
            end

            if(a(i,j) ~= a(i,k)+G(k,j)) % w(u,v)=G(u,v) in unweighted graph)
                continue;
            end  

            % sigma(s,v) = sigma(s,v) + sigma(s,u);
            b(i,j) = b(i,j) + b(k,i);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You may find [Eric Lippert's blog post "How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to be helpful.

Comment: thanks. but useless answer.